# Unity Build Problem, cant change product name

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have Unity build problem, product name (apk name on phone)is always old name. No matter what I do, the same old name comes out.

Help me please. Need all comments...

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

It´s probably a cache problem.
Try to reboot your phone and empty the application data cache.
Android UI is caching apk name and icon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the `AutoNamer.package`. If you have `AutoNamer` you have to change your product name in it.